# Mage::log() doesn't work in admin

Tags: magento, logging, admin, mage

I have a simple question. Why doesn't Mage::log work in an Adminhtml block??

I know the file is being read/loaded because when I put in `die()` on the first line of the file I get a blank screen, and removing/renaming the file also causes trouble.

Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it's pretty simple...

Even though logging was enabled in the "Main Website" scope, it wasn't in the "Default Configuration" scope. Enabling it there as well did it for the admin section.

Answer (score 1):

Check xml config file:
    app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml

```
<log>
    <active>1</active>
    <file>system.log</file>
    <exception_file>exception.log</exception_file>
</log>
```

And if active = 0 update db:

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET value = 0 WHERE `path` LIKE 'dev/log/active'
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, though I have already found an easier solution. Forgot to accept it.